# Converting an xls file to dat using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am working on a vbscript which is required to run and pass args from command prompt and will convert an xls file (with multiple sheets) to a dat file.The format of the dat file is specified in an external XML file.

The xml file looks like the following

```html
<RECORD>
<CD>
<Name>HEAD</Name>
<Length>4</Length>
</CD>
<CD>
<Name>ORGCODE</Name>
<Length>5</Length>
</CD>
<CD>
<Name>ORGNAME</Name>
<Length>30</Length>
</CD><CD>
<Name>SCNAME</Name>
<Length>30</Length>
</CD>
<CD>
<Name>FILLER</Name>
<Length>290</Length>
</CD>
</RECORD>
```

I want  to get the text and count(which is 5 in this case) of length and then add the text to dictionary. I will be using it later to decide if and how many blank spaces I need in the dat file.

I have tried the following but it didn't worked

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

objXML.Load(fileloc)
Set obj =  objXML.getElementsByTagName("Length")

For i = 1 To obj.length 
    objDict.Add i, obj.Item(i).Value()
Next
```

'========================================================

```
 Dim objXML : Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  objXML.async = False
  objXML.load fileloc

    Dim sXPath : sXPath = "/RECORD/CD/Length"
    Dim ndlX : Set ndlX = objXML.selectNodes(sXPath)

    For i = 1 To ndlX.length
    msgbox "found"
    Next
```

Following is the code that I earlier wrote and works through QTP

'======================================================

```
Set objDict = CreateObject ("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objXML  = XMLUtil.CreateXML()
objXML.LoadFile(fileloc)
Set obj = objXML.ChildElementsByPath("/RECORD/CD/Length")

    For i = 1 To obj.Count
        objDict.Add i, obj.Item(i).Value()
    Next
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Few points: The for loop should iterate from `i=0` to `i=ndlX.length-1` or `obj.length-1`. Also, the xpath mentioned in the 2nd last code should be `sXPath = "/RECORD/CD/Length"`

Comment: obj.length is coming up as 0 and I am sorry I have edited the question, I am using "/RECORD/CD/Length"